# Hide scrollbar but still being able to scroll without using -webkit-scrollbar

Tags: html, css, angular

does someone know a way to hide the scrollbar and still being able to scroll but without using  -webkit-scrollbar {display:none}?, the thing is I could do it that way but in my company they use SonarQube and it shows and unexpected error so it wouldn't let us deploy

SonarQube error:

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for a CSS fix or Javascript?

Comment: why would you hide the scroll? :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `overflow: hidden;` in your element or in the whole body to hide all scrollbars like this:

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Or if you want just to hide the horizontal one, you can do it like this:

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

To hide exclusively the vertical one, you go like this:

```css
body {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```